# Upload file to S3 bucket from web server

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-net

How to upload files from the Web server to s3 bucket in .NET? Web server has read and write access to the bucket hence no AWS key is needed.

I have previously used S3 SDK and Access Key to upload, how do I handle connection to s3 bucket in current scenario ? Does S3 SDK facilitates this ?

Would to be grateful to get some information or resouces to follow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A simple google search for "upload to s3 from .net" brings you to this article:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HLuploadFileDotNet.html

Comment: Hi @Jack thank you, i will check the Article.I am new to web development and s3 and may be I complicated thinkin. I was more thinking on how does authentication work  while connecting to s3 bucket without providing any key .I will follow SDK documents to see if it has explanation.

Comment: Gotcha, well assuming your web server is an EC2 instance, you can use IAM to give your EC2 instances access to S3 and therefore you don't need to use access keys.

Comment: Try this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34057679/aws-s3-bucket-access-from-ec2

Comment: That makes sense now about authentication, I will update how it goes.Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to instantiate an `Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client` without providing an access key or a secret key?  You can pass the constructor `null`s.  For example:

```
var client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(null, null, s3Config)
```

Comment: Yes instantiate the S3 client and perform upload without providing an access key or a secret key. I will follow your suggestion and update the status.Thanks your for prompt reply