# Access S3 bucket from all instances having a particular IAM role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am having an S3 bucket which is not publicly accessible . I need to access it from my Ec2 instances which are having an IAM role attached for get/put s3 object policies.

Lets say my IAM role is - S3AccessRole, what could be the  s3 bucket policy that can enable this access for all instances having that particular role.

FYI, if I enable the public access on s3 bucket, I am able to copy objects in ec2.

Comment: can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34057679/aws-s3-bucket-access-from-ec2) question be the answer to yours?

Comment: Thanks . That totally worked. :-)